# Pregunta sobre relación de dependencia sintáctica (oración condicional)

Tags: sintaxis

> Escribió una nota, imaginándose lo que él le hubiera respondido a ella
>   si lo quisiera de verdad.

Me gustaría saber si lo he entendido bien:

(a) aquí tenemos una oración completiva (con el subjuntivo (*hubiera respondido*) causado por el verbo *imaginarse*) y una oración condicional (*si lo quisiera de verdad*). ¿Se puede decir que la oración condicional depende de la oración completiva?

(b) y una preguntita más: ¿Se puede aplicar los términos *apódosis* y *prótasis* a las dos oraciones arriba mencionadas o solo son aplicables a las oraciones como „*Si tengo tiempo, te ayudo*“?

Gracias

Comment: Nota: el tiempo verbal correcto en la frase sería "habría respondido". Creo que ya hemos tenido debates al respecto por aquí.

Comment: Yo concuerdo en que hay alternativas a "el hubiera respondido" :habria respondido, hubiese/hubiera respondido, respondería. Por otro lado, todas las alternativas dependen del significado exacto aunque la construcción tendría las mismas características: Oración condicional, completiva, apódosis y prótasis. Por lo visto tienes una clara idea de los que preguntas y quizá sólo busques una confirmación. Por tal motivo, te invito a que respondas a tu pregunta haciendo una exposición más detallada.

Answer (score 1):

a) "¿Se puede decir que la oración condicional depende de la oración completiva?"

Yo no diría que la oración condicional depende de la oración completiva. Yo diría que ambas son la misma: 
`"lo que él le hubiera respondido a ella si lo quisiera de verdad"`.

b) ¿Se puede aplicar los términos *apódosis* y *prótasis*?

Sí se pueden aplicar. En concreto, la prótasis es `"lo quisiera de verdad"`, y la apódosis es `"lo que él le hubiera respondido"`.

Prótasis: Es la parte de la oración condicional que introduce la hipótesis, suele ir precedida por la conjunción si.

Apódosis: Indica la consecuencia de lo expresado por la condición.

Vamos por partes.

A. La oración (subordinada sustantiva o) completiva es `"lo que él le hubiera respondido a ella si lo quisiera de verdad."`

A.1. Razón: como indica aquí ([oración completiva](http://hispanoteca.eu/Lexikon%20der%20Linguistik/o/ORACI%C3%93N%20COMPLETIVA.htm)): "Para reconocer la función que desempeña en una oración compleja la oración subordinada sustantiva, se puede sustituir por un sustantivo o un sintagma nominal, por un pronombre demostrativo neutro o por el pronombre personal lo (o 'eso')."
--> `"Escribió una nota, imaginándose ESO"`

A.2. También podría escribirse como "Escribió una nota, imaginándose qué él le hubiera respondido a ella si lo quisiera de verdad.". En esta forma, 'qué' es un adverbio interrogativo más típico de las subordinadas sustantivas (completivas).

B. Oración condicional: "lo que él le hubiera respondido, si le quisiera de verdad", equivalente a "si le quisiera de verdad, él le hubiera respondido esto".

Simplificándola como "si X, Y", [según RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=uqFr1XT7vD6KF3oDZL):

- X (prótasis) (`"le quisiera de verdad"`) es una oración subordinada condicional de Y (apódosis) (`"él le hubiera respondido esto"`)
- Normalmente, en los enunciados condicionales, la subordinada antecede a la principal: `Si no vas a venir` (prótasis), `avísame antes` (apódosis). Las oraciones condicionales pueden ser de dos tipos:
- 1.1.1. "reales". Se denominan así porque la condición expresada es un hecho posible o realizable.
- 1.1.2. "irreales". Se denominan así porque la condición expresada se considera no realizada en el pasado, e irrealizable o improbable en el presente o en el futuro. El verbo de la prótasis va en subjuntivo.
- **caso a**) Si la condición se refiere al presente o al futuro, la prótasis va en pretérito imperfecto o copretérito de subjuntivo y la apódosis en condicional simple o pospretérito: `Si me tocara/tocase la lotería, me compraría un coche`.
- caso b) Si la condición se refiere al pasado, la prótasis va en pretérito pluscuamperfecto o antepretérito de subjuntivo y en la apódosis se emplea este mismo tiempo, preferentemente la forma en -ra, aunque también se admite la forma en -se: `Si hubiera/hubiese tenido dinero, me hubiera/hubiese comprado un coche`; el condicional compuesto o antepospretérito: `Si hubieras/hubieses estudiado, habrías aprobado`; o el condicional simple o pospretérito: `Si hubiera/hubiese terminado los estudios, hoy tendría un trabajo mejor`.

C. [Interdependencia en sintaxis](http://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/cauce/pdf/cauce20-21/cauce20-21_33.pdf). Respecto a la dependencia que aprecias, si te refieres a la dependencia entre la oración condicional y la oración **compleja** (no la completiva), en la página 712 del vínculo comenta el caso de las oraciones condicionales como uno de los casos de interdependencia (o interordinación, como sugiere que sea denominado, por eufonía).

Pero a mi parecer, según has formulado tu pregunta, entiendo que la oración condicional y la completiva son la misma.